# Updating a Node image field from an external URL

Tags: 8, nodes, files

I need to retrieve an image from an external URL and then save the image on Drupal's file system, and then set the image as the image for a node. In D7, this was a pretty simple task, but it's causing me issues in D8. In D7, here is what we have:

```
$file_info = system_retrieve_file($url, 'public://course_images/', TRUE);
if(!empty($file_info) && $file_info->fid) {
    $entity->field_image[0] = array('fid' => $file_info->fid);
}
```

I am trying the same thing in D8 but just receive this error `Value is not valid entity` which provides ZERO actual information about exactly what is wrong.

In D8, here is what I currently have:

```
$file = system_retrieve_file($image_url, 'public://course_images/', TRUE, FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);

if ($file && $file->id) {
  $course_node->set('field_image', [
    'target_id' => $file->id,
    'alt' => 'alt text',
    'title' => 'title'
  ]);
}
```

I've also tried using `$file->id()` and `$file->fid` with no luck. I just don't know how to access the file entity id!

I have tried to debug the `$file` object to figure this out using the logger

```
Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice('<pre><code>' . print_r($file, TRUE) . '</code></pre>');
```

but this code is in a cron job and adding that logger just makes the cron job fail with no error other than 'Cron cannot get lock' (again, another error with little to no information).

I can see that my file is being saved properly, but how can I access it's node ID after saving to be able to set as the target_id of the image field?

EDIT:

I moved all this code into an endpoint instead of a cron for debugging purposes. Here is my endpoint:

```
  function edxServiceTest(Request $request) {
    $course_node = Node::create([
      'type' => 'courses',
      'uid' => 1
    ]);
    $course_node->set('title', 'Test');
    $course_node->set('langcode', 'en');
    $course_node->set('status', NODE_PUBLISHED);

    $image_url = 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fthewowstyle.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F01%2Fnature-images.jpg&f=1&nofb=1';

    $file = system_retrieve_file($image_url, 'public://course_images/', TRUE, FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);

    if ($file && $file->fid) {
      $course_node->set('field_image', [
        'target_id' => $file->fid,
        'alt' => 'Alt Text',
        'title' => 'Title',
      ]);
    } else {
      return new JsonResponse('error', 400);
    }

    $course_node->save();

    return new JsonResponse('success', 201);
  }
```

Here's what's occurring:

1. If I try to use `$file->id()` as the target, the endpoint runs successfully but the node is not added and there is no errors that occur.
2. If I try to use `$file->fid` as the target, the endpoint runs into an unexpected error `Value is not a valid entity`.

Comment: After set value field_image, you have to save node `$course_node->save();`

Comment: Do you get an error when you access `$file->id()` or `$file->fid`, or do you think that isn't the correct way to get the file ID (which isn't its node ID) because using `$file->id()` as target ID causes any error?

Comment: As it happens for every entities, `$file->id()` returns its ID. With file entities, it's possible to get the same value with `$file->fid`. Only `id()` is exposed from `FileInterface`; when a method/function returns an object implementing `FileInterface`, `id()` is safer to use, as an object implementing that interface doesn't necessarily have any `fid` property.

Comment: As for the value an image field accepts for the *target_id* property, that is the ID of a file entity. Replace `$file->id` with `$file->id()`, and the code should work. If it doesn't work, the error is in another place.

Comment: @Jonh I am saving the node, I only put in the portion of the. ode relevant to the question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I found out my main issue was this particular image field doesn't have a 'title', so the save was silently failing. The correct solution is to use `$file->id()` to get the file's entity id. But still I find VERY BAD that this error doesn't actually save the entity without an error...

Comment: The question should show code that allows to reproduce the issue. You say that particular image field doesn't have a title, but the code is setting the *title* property for the image field with a literal string.